# TreeMap and click event

Tags: jquery-plugins

How to generate onclick event in TreeMap

Answer (score 1):

I think your are asking for Jquery treemap plugin. If so, I have done this once. check the below code

```
 $('.treemapCell').each(function () {

    $(this).find('span').click(function () {

         //Code 
                });
    });
```

Cheers!!